# How we solve issue with uploading image in WordPress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress admin when I try to add any image to Media section it gives error
The uploaded file could not be moved to uploads/2018/03

To solve this problem, I tried the following:
1) I changed permission to folder uploads and all its subfolders to 777 
2) I followed the article https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/fix-uploaded-file-not-moved-wp-contentuploads/ and changed owner of uploads directory to nobody

but its not working anyway…

Same things works fine on other domain on same server.

Can someone please give a hint on what may have gone wrong here?

Comment: Who owns that directory you at trying to upload to?

Comment: Does your Apache server run as `nobody` or `www-data` (or something else)?

Comment: Nobody owns that directory which i trying to upload

Comment: Our apache server run as nobody and nobody owns that directory
i also gave grant access to nobody user. i restart the apache server, and try to upload file but it still gives error like this:The uploaded file could not be moved to uploads/2018/03.